# How to turn an Object (data from database) into an array and show one of its keys on the simulator

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-native-flatlist

So I am trying to render my Firebase Database onto my Android simulator and it is showing an error, in which the solution is to convert an object into an array, but I do not know-how.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {FlatList, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {employeesFetch} from '../actions';
import ListItem from './ListItem';

class EmployeeList extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.employeesFetch();
}

renderRow(employee) {
            return <ListItem employee={employee}/>;
    };

    render(){
        console.log(this.props.employees);
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                data={Object.keys(this.props.employees)}
                renderItem={this.renderRow}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const employees = _.map(state.employees, (val, uid) => {
        return { ...val, uid };
    });

    return { employees };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { employeesFetch })(EmployeeList);
```

That mapStateToProps helper is supposed to create a variable called employees (if I am not wrong, I am just learning to code) but when I write that down like this:

```
<FlatList
data=employees
renderItem={this.renderRow}
/>
```

It says that employees is not defined. Just in case, I will add the ListItem file to show what I have done there.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import {CardSection} from './common';

class ListItem extends Component {
  render () {
    const { name } = this.props.employee;

    return (
      <CardSection>
        <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>
          {name}
        </Text>
      </CardSection>
    );
  }
}
export default ListItem;
```

I expect the output to be a list showing the employees (recorded in Firebase Database) on the screen, but is showing an error: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, phone, shift, uid}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: What's the initial state for your reducer?

Comment: An empty object

Comment: I think I see one issue on your renderRow function.

It seems you're trying to get the property 'item' from the object your function is receiving and print that out inside of your 'Text' tag.

Try printing 'item.somePropHere' and see what happens, if this breaks something up.

Then remove the curly braces from the '{item}' parameter, you'll get the full object into that function and you can access it like 'item.somePropHere'

Comment: I changed the code since I created a separate file (I'll update the post), now it is doing fine: it is showing every "ListItem" component but not the name of the employee.